# Build a UI / Input form for a text file

Tags: angularjs, html, excel, csv, vba

i have a text file which is used as a input for other system
It contains data like

city,date
new york,17/02/2012
chicago,17/03/2011

I need to build a frontend on top of this text file to validate any user input .
Basically need to make sure date is entered correct etc .

I need to build a form/web page anything which will take input from user  and have a text file as above as a database .

can you please tell me which is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular, you're probably okay with Node.js (assumption). That being the case, you can use Node's native file system capabilities to take input from an html form and write it to the text file. Here's a [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-and-handling-forms-in-node-js/) to a SitePoint article that walks through setting up the form. You'd just have to take the inputs and use fs.writeFile() to... write the file. Also, the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) for fs.